# Who gives the `eventinterface` a `realm` in DOM SPEC?

Tags: javascript, dom, chromium

I'm reading [DOM SPEC](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#constructing-events), and I meet the `realm` and I don't know what is this. According the SPEC said, it's a something of ECMA. I have learned JS, but I haven't learned about `realm`!

In addition, a part of content in `constructing events` section , `To create an event using eventInterface`, If I'm not mistaken `eventInterface` means [this](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-event), but I don't found that need to give `realm`! Who gives the `eventinterface` a `realm`? It is chrome's blink??

Answer (score 0):

From https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-code-realms:

> Before it is evaluated, all ECMAScript code must be associated with a
> **realm**. Conceptually, a realm consists of a set of intrinsic objects, an ECMAScript global environment, all of the ECMAScript code
> that is loaded within the scope of that global environment, and other
> associated state and resources.

It is perfectly ok that you did not hear about realm. As a developer we can not create it, a JS engine controls realm creation when starts to execute a code.

When you create an event with new Event(), you create an object in JS and a realm is just a place where an event object is placed.

Comment: from dom.spec - "Let event be the result of creating a new object using eventInterface. If realm is non-null, then use that Realm;". 
It means that object is created in the Realm.

Comment: You can use markdown to correctly mark what's quoted in your answer.

Comment: @AndreySmolko I know these are additional behaviors(in blink). For example, I learned init event, and then I can found some of behaviors in Chrome's blink. But  now, I can't found the realm in [Blink source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/third_party/blink/renderer/core/dom/events/).

Comment: @AndreySmolko Thanks for your reply, can you add some source files link of blink?